# Como fazer um select que me traga números de telefone

Tags: jquery, mysql

Trabalho em um Market Place para compra e vendas.
Eu quero buscar telefones de nossos vendedores em diferentes tabelas: Comentários, Conversas e Items.

Como posso fazer para buscar somente números, desde que haja mais de 8 dígitos nessas diferentes tabelas?

Comment: Poste a estrutura das tabelas que você tem telefone. Ajuda a entendermos melhor o que realmente quer. Não entendi porque o uso da tag Jquery.

Comment: Mysql e php? Está usando algum framework? Poderia dar detalhes do que fez até agora?